# unable to use String.includes() method on a function's parameter

Tags: javascript, string, google-apps-script

I am attempting to determine whether a passed value to the function addToCalendar (sport) includes the String *"soccer"* by using the code below:

```
function addToCalendar(sport, date, time){

  var sportName = String(sport);
  Logger.log(sportName.includes("Soccer"));

}
```

However, I am getting this error: **TypeError: Cannot find function includes in object Soccer: Girls JV. (line 77, file "Code")** how would I fix this?

Comment: Where are you running this function? In a browser?

Comment: @bugs yes, in the Google Apps script editor

Comment: String.prototype.includes is an ES6 feature, it might not be supported by that editor yet

Comment: @bugs ok, is their another way to determine whether a string contains a string of letters in a specific order?

Comment: sure, you can use `sportName.indexOf('Soccer')`, which returns -1 if the substring is not contained, or the correct index if otherwise

Comment: @bugs ok, thanks. If you add what you said here as a solution i'll mark this post as solved

Comment: @Lontronix the error does not correspond with the code you've shown. You are leaving something out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`String.prototype.includes` is an ES6 feature, it might not be supported by that environment yet. An alternative way of achieving the same result is using `sportName.indexOf('Soccer')`, which returns -1 if the substring is not contained, or the correct index otherwise.

[String.prototype.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

Comment: Of course this is true, but I doubt it is the case here

Comment: *"supported by that editor"* would be better stated as *"supported in that environment"* since it is not an editor related issue

Comment: @charlietfl correct, that's what I meant. I'll edit the answer to be more precise

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated [**`String.prototype.includes`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) is not yet supported in Apps Script. However, you can leverage the following polyfill [available from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes#Polyfill):

```
if (!String.prototype.includes) {
  String.prototype.includes = function(search, start) {
    'use strict';
    if (typeof start !== 'number') {
      start = 0;
    }

    if (start + search.length > this.length) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return this.indexOf(search, start) !== -1;
    }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an ExtendScript function to check a strings contents for .contains().

```
function contains (word, content) {
    for(var i = 0; i < (word.length-content.length+1); i++){
        if(word.substring(i, i+content.length) == content) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).